# I'm stuck in Flutter beta

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't remember signing up for any flutter beta programs but, today I noticed that whenever I'm creating a new project it's based on a beta flutter sdk.

sdk version in my pubspec.yaml seems like this

`sdk: ">=2.17.0-266.5.beta <3.0.0"`

and I can see more updates and bugs.
I don't want to be in Beta. How can I leave this.

Comment: you can change channel to stable by using command flutter channel stable and then you can create new flutter project  and you will be fine with stable flutter sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write `flutter channel stable` in a terminal to switch to the "normal" version